# register C# assemblie and use functions in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2005, assemblies

Suppose I have a static class in C#:

```
public static class Math
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }


    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void Void(int a, int b)
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }

}
```

I know by [@faester´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364152/clr-assembly-c-inside-sql-server) that to use this function in SQL we do:

```
 EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'clr enabled', 1
    GO
    RECONFIGURE
    GO
    -- CONSIDER: DROP ASSEMBLY SqlClr
    GO
    CREATE ASSEMBLY SqlClr 
    FROM 'pathtoassembly'
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
    GO
    SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies
    GO
    CREATE FUNCTION [MathAdd] (@a int, @b int)
    RETURNS INT 
    AS EXTERNAL NAME [SqlClr].Math.[Add]
    GO 
    CREATE PROCEDURE [Void] @a INT, @b INT
    AS EXTERNAL NAME [SqlClr].Math.[Void]
    GO 
    SELECT dbo.MathAdd (1, 2)
    EXEC void 1, 2
```

To do this example *first I added a **main** in the c# file*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

public static class Math
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }


    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void Void(int a, int b)
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }

}
```

So, when I execute the SQL code... What path do I add. I was doing:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY SqlClr 
    FROM 'C:\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
    GO
```

Obiously I must not add the **.exe**, so tried with the **sln** file and the cs file but can not get it to work...

I am getting the following, error:

> Configuration option 'clr enabled' changed from 1 to 1. Run the
>   RECONFIGURE statement to install. Msg 6501, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
>   CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because it could not open the physical file
>   "C:\Visual Studio
>   2005\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe":
>   5(Acces denied.).

My question besides what to put in the **path**, is about how to build the c# code, do I only built it like any other program, do I add something else...

- What is it mising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect that it does't like the console app...

For a walkthrough see http://www.setfocus.com/technicalarticles/articles/clrfunctionforsqlserver.aspx

Some interesting resources see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k.aspx