# Beyond SOUNDEX & DIFFERENCE - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, analysis, text-analysis

I am using `SOUNDEX` & `DIFFERENCE` functions to  do some analysis on the data present in the table.

But this function fails at below type of data. The `ITEM TYPE` & `ITEM SIZE` are completely different.

```
SELECT SOUNDEX('ITEM TYPE'), SOUNDEX('ITEM SIZE')

op:-

I350    I350

For DIFFERENCE op: - 4
```

I understand every analysis that human mind do can not be coded, still I would like to ask, are there exists any other functions in `SQL Server` that will help me out on my next level analysis ?

Comment: `SOUNDEX` wasn't just made up by the SQL Server developers, it's a "well known" [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)

Comment: You could try looking into the Jaro Winkler algorithm, e.g. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Fuzzy+Match/65702/

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this is not the answer to my concern :(

Comment: You will probably find this helpful:  https://www.archives.gov/research/census/soundex.html.

Comment: You're using functions to do analysis. That's probably the most generic statement you could make here. What is your concern? That `soundex` (which is essentially a hashing algorithm) returns the same value for two different inputs? Hashes exhibit that behavior.

Comment: [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) is a terrible algorithm for anything in the real world. It was developed to try and find matches for surnames, but it reduces everything to too small a range. I suspect the only reason it's still around is because Knuth thought it was an interesting algorithm, intellectually. Difference is a bit better, but also not great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an algorithm, such as [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance).

> The Damerau–Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum
>   number of operations (consisting of insertions, deletions or
>   substitutions of a single character, or transposition of two adjacent
>   characters) required to change one word into the other.

There are T-SQL implementations, such as [this one by Steve Hatchett](http://blog.softwx.net/2015/01/optimizing-damerau-levenshtein_19.html).
Alternatively, you can use [an implementation in C#](http://blog.softwx.net/2015/01/optimizing-damerau-levenshtein_15.html), compile a DLL and load it into SQL CLR. Compiled version should be faster.

More info on loading CLR assemblies into SQL @ [CLR Assembly C# inside SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364152/).