# Fuzzy match in SQL Server when using Chinese_Hong_Kong_Stroke_90_CI_AS collation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose we create a table as follows:

```
create table my_table (
id int, 
city nvarchar(256) collate Chinese_Hong_Kong_Stroke_90_CI_AS)

INSERT INTO my_table (id, city)
VALUES (1, 'Shanghai');

INSERT INTO my_table (id, city)
VALUES (2, 'Shandong');

INSERT INTO my_table (id, city)
VALUES (3, 'Shanxi');

INSERT INTO my_table (id, city)
VALUES (4, 'Shaanxi');
```

There are now four records in my_table:

```
id  city
1   Shanghai
2   Shandong
3   Shanxi
4   Shaanxi
```

The following SQL queries return the same number. How to avoid this error?

```
select top 1 id from my_table order by DIFFERENCE(city, 'Shanghai') desc
select top 1 id from my_table order by DIFFERENCE(city, 'Shandong') desc
```

Another problem:

```
select top 1 id from my_table order by DIFFERENCE(city, 'Shannxi') desc
```

Returns 3 when the correct answer should be 4.

Comment: I assume this is for SQL Server? Then please add the tag. And I cannot reproduce that: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=a2481dcff2b4becd215c140c05d66783

Comment: Are you sure?  With the setup described I get '2'.  Maybe set up a fiddle as @stickybit suggests.

Comment: Please give us more information, What is your table "collation"? and what is the city column "datatype"?

Comment: I add more descriptions and change the query. You can test it now.

Comment: I have tested the query on my SQL Server and found the result ``` 1 ```

Comment: Did you try both queries?

Comment: The collation of column `city` is `Chinese_Hong_Kong_Stroke_90_CI_AS`

Comment: Any other methods to get the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the collation of your column. As per the docs `SOUNDEX` & `DIFFERENCE` are collation dependent.

A possible solution is:

```
select top 1 id
from my_table
order by DIFFERENCE(city collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 'Shanghai') desc

select top 1 id
from my_table
order by DIFFERENCE(city collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 'Shandong') desc
```

I think I would add another column with a `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation which stores exactly the same value as `city`.

Although it would be of interest to know exactly what you are trying to accomplish? Because in your current collation those 2 words apparently sound exactly the same.

Its also worth reading [Beyond SOUNDEX & DIFFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389034/beyond-soundex-difference-sql-server)

Comment: Thank you, Dale. I need to get the town names of a city name, which may contains error. Your solution is good. However, it cannot solve my new problem as shown above.

Comment: Shame you didn't include all the data in your original question. I think you're going to have to investigate using the `Damerau–Levenshtein distance` to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry for not posting all the questions in the beginning. How to start with `Damerau–Levenshtein distance`?