# Send SMS via Sql server or copy text in Excel and send it from mobile

Tags: sql-server, iphone, excel, sms

I know this is not the right place to ask this type of question but I searched google and found nothing about my topic

I want to send different sms to multiple persons via SQL server beside sms gateway is there any way to send it via sql server or transfer data and mobile number to excel sheet and send it via iPhone

Comment: If you know it's not the right place to ask, why are you asking knowing that there's a high chance of your topic being locked? SQL Server doesn't natively have the ability to send an SMS, you have to use third party applications to do so. As for transferring data to a mobile (specifically an iPhone) and emailing out? That sounds like a terribly manual solution. You would be better searching for products that can send an SMS and integrate with SQL Server. If they have a trial, they use that and see if it works and then, if it suits your needs, purchase it.

Comment: you need an sms service provider to handle the process of sending messages. The one that we use is using an api, so we developed an application that handles the API and connect to SQL Server, reading the sms table which contain all sms required information (receiver number, message) along with error handling for each message. Then, we automate it via the application (reading the SMS table only whenever the trigger is fired) this will make the application send the SMS. I hope this will give you a good start.

Comment: I forgot, some sms providers uses emails system, so you send the sms to a provided email, and then the provider handle the rest. So, it depends on the provider you choose.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do such thing is by registering and call a .NET dll assembly from SQL server.

for more details:

> [CLR Assembly C# inside SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364152/clr-assembly-c-sharp-inside-sql-server)

Once you register the assembly correctly, you can call a C# function from inside the SQL. i suggest you do a URL get call, that can call a page at your server, which will do the API call from there.

this is very useful as you can mix it with SQL statement for example.

You can write something like:

```
Select CallURL('http://localhost/SMSgateway' + PhoneNum) from Users.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your great responses I found an easier way to do it in iPhone using SA Group Text
just need to upload excel file on it with phone number and message contents and it will send it